# JQuery, cannot read property length

Tags: jquery

here i have a simple problem
in my page:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


    msg = "[{'CodiceProvincia' : '046','Provincia' : 'Lucca'}{'CodiceProvincia' : '108','Provincia' : 'Monza e della Brianza'}{'CodiceProvincia' :'109','Provincia' : 'Fermo'}{'CodiceProvincia' : '037','Provincia' : 'Bologna'}]";

    //  var msg = $.parseJSON(msgg);

    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_dlProvinciaResidenza").empty();

    var myDropDownList = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_dlProvinciaResidenza');


    $.each(msg, function (i, item) {
        alert(item.CodiceProvincia);
    });
  
    $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(msg), function () {
        myDropDownList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CodiceProvincia']).html(this['Provincia']));
    });



});
```

```html
           
                <span id="Span1">provincia</span>
          <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$dlProvinciaResidenza" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$dlProvinciaResidenza\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_dlProvinciaResidenza" tabindex="5" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
             
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_Label3">Comune</span>
                    <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$dlComuneResidenza" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_dlComuneResidenza" tabindex="6" class="form-control input-sm">

 </select>
                                        
    </html>
```

i am using jquery to load cities in my dropdown list, but i canno fix the error

> :"cannot read property lenght"

in this example page i used a simple variable named msg with the data, but in my real page i use a webservice, this just to make the question simpler

what can i do?

Comment: We would like to see how you've coded your `webservice`. Until then the question remains unclear..

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in your webservice as the json example you provided is corrupt. See it working here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var msg = $.parseJSON('[{"CodiceProvincia": "046","Provincia" : "Lucca"},{"CodiceProvincia" : "108","Provincia" : "Monza e della Brianza"},{"CodiceProvincia" :"109","Provincia" : "Fermo"},{"CodiceProvincia" : "037","Provincia" : "Bologna"}]');

  var myDropDownList = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_dlProvinciaResidenza');
  myDropDownList.empty();


  $.each(msg, function(i, item) {
    myDropDownList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CodiceProvincia']).html(this['Provincia']));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="Span1">provincia</span>
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$dlProvinciaResidenza" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$dlProvinciaResidenza\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_dlProvinciaResidenza"
tabindex="5" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your json is non-well formed.

You need coma between elements and double quotes

exemple :

> [{"CodiceProvincia": "046","Provincia" : "Lucca"},{"CodiceProvincia" : "108","Provincia" : "Monza e della Brianza"},...

2.

> :"cannot read property lenght"

is cause by first foreach.

```
 $.each(msg, function (i, item) {
        alert(item.CodiceProvincia);
    });
```

At this moment "msg" is a string, foreach is impossible
You need convert "msg" variable to json object

```
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(msg), function (i, item) {
        alert(item.CodiceProvincia);
    });
```